# Как с помощью запросов python отправить запрос в form-data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, requests, formdata

Есть вот такая форма:

```
-----------------------------12217157663724032382916690511
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

Какой-то текст
-----------------------------12217157663724032382916690511

-----------------------------12217157663724032382916690511
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

1
-----------------------------12217157663724032382916690511
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="numbers"

Числа
-----------------------------12217157663724032382916690511
```

Как отправить в такие формы запрос через python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это POST запрос с типом [`multipart/form-data`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data) ([RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578)). Текст внутри каждого блока получающая сторона будет расценивать как будто это файл. Сделать такой запрос можно с помощью модуля `requests`, передаваемые данные передаем в параметр `files`:

```
import requests

data = dict(
    text=(None, "Какой-то текст"),
    submit=(None, "1"),
    numbers=(None, "Числа"),
)
r = requests.post(, 'http://some.url', files=data)
```

`None` нужно, чтобы в блоках имя поля не подставлялось имя файла, иначе будет, например, не

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"
```

а

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"; filename="text"
```

Для проверки, что передаются данные именно того вида, как вам нужно, можно выполнить такой код (тут запрос не отправляется, а только подготавливается):

```
import requests

data = dict(
    text=(None, "Какой-то текст"),
    submit=(None, "1"),
    numbers=(None, "Числа"),
)
r = requests.Request('POST', 'http://some.url', files=data)

print(r.prepare().body.decode("utf-8"))
```

Результат:

```
--b7c74bca047cc4f63bd57f7ab8aace6a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

Какой-то текст
--b7c74bca047cc4f63bd57f7ab8aace6a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

1
--b7c74bca047cc4f63bd57f7ab8aace6a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="numbers"

Числа
--b7c74bca047cc4f63bd57f7ab8aace6a--
```

Вид ограничителей (`--b7c74bca047cc4f63bd57f7ab8aace6a`) не так важен, все будет и так работать.

Код основе ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/4752653